# How many times does $5$ appear in this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> How many times does $5$ appear in the factorisation of $1! \times 2! \times ... \times 100!$?

I know the formula for $n!$ that a prime $p$ appears in it $\frac n p + \frac n {p^2} + ...$ times, but that is hard to do for this.

I'll try anyway,

From $1! \to 4!$ $0$ times,

From $5! \to 9!$: $\sum = 1(9 - 5 + 1) = 5$ times,

From $10! \to 14!$: $\sum = 2(14 - 10 + 1) = 10$ times,

$...$

Hence, from $1! \to 24!$, it appears: $5(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = \frac{5(5)(4)} 2 = 50$

But this is getting long, and I should only be given $7$ minutes for the problem anyway.

Comment: are you multiplying the factorials?

Comment: yes I wrote $x$ thats why

Comment: $\cdot$ or $\times$ just easier to know what you mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1!\times2!\times3!\times...\times100!=1\times2^{99}\times3^{98}\times...100$$

Extract numbers with $5$ as factor:

$$5^{96}\times10^{91}\times15^{86}\times...\times100$$

Extract the $5$s (and pay attention to $25^{76}$, $50^{51}$, $75^{26}$, and $100$ which have more than one $5$):

$$5^{96+91+86+81+...+6+1}\times5^{76+51+26+1}=5^{20\times(1+9)\times9/2+7\times10}\times5^{154}=5^{1124}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are doing fine.  Now note that you add $2$ more at $25, 50, 75, 100$, so the sum becomes $5(1+2+3+4+6+7+8+9+10+12+13+14+15+16+18+19+20+21+22)+24$, where the last $24$ comes from $100!$.  The sum inside the brackets is $\frac 12\cdot 22 \cdot 23-5-11-17$, so the final result is $5(\frac 12\cdot 22 \cdot 23-5-11-17)+24=5(11\cdot 23-33)+24=5(276-50)+24=1124$

Answer (score 0):

Partial summation gives a nice formula:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{i=1}^{100}\nu_5(i!)&=&100\cdot\nu_5(100!)-\sum_{i=1}^{99}i\cdot\nu_5(i+1)\\[0.2cm]&=&100\cdot 24-\sum_{k=2}^{100}(k-1)\cdot\nu_5(k)\\[0.2cm]&=&2400-\sum_{n=1}^{20}(5n-1)-\sum_{m=1}^{4}(25m-1)\\[0.2cm]&=&2400-1030-246=\color{red}{1124}.\end{eqnarray*} $$